# Show that every orientation reversing homeomorphism of the real line has a fixed point.

Tags: dynamical-systems

A homeomorphism f is said to be orientation reversing if for any $x<y<z$ we have $f(z)<f(y)<f(x)$. Show that every orientation reversing homeomorphism of the real line has a fixed point.

This is a question on my assignment sheet (not for credit) that I've been thinking about for days but not made any progress on. I feel like this will be easy to answer once I find the trick, any hints would be great!

Comment: IVT${}{}{}{}{}$?

Comment: I was thinking that but I'm not quite sure how to apply it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $f(0)=0$, we are done.

If $f(0)>0$, then $f(f(0))<f(0)$, and if $f(0)<0$, then $f(f(0))>f(0)$.
In both cases, we have poitns $x_1,x_2$ with  $f(x_1)<x_1$ and  $f(x_2)>x_2$. Then the Intermediate Value Theorem tells us that the continuous function $x\mapsto f(x)-x$ has a zero between $x_1$ and $x_2$, i.e., $f$ has a fixed point.

Comment: So we don't need *homeomorphism*, just *continuous*.

Comment: @ihf I'm not sure what your comment means, but the hypothesis that it *$f$ is an orientation reversing homeomorphism* has been used in this proof, i.e. in the case $f(0)>0$ we may conclude $f(f(0))<f(0)$. This proof would break down if you only assumed $f$ was continuous.

Comment: @LeeMosher, I meant, does $f$ *need* to be a bijection? With continuous inverse? Sure, *orientation reversing* is essential.

Comment: What should be the meaning of "orientation reversing" for a map which is not a homeomorphism?

Comment: @PaulFrost, $x \mapsto \arctan(-x)$ is an orientation reversing map $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ that is not a homeomorphism (though it is a homeomorphism with its image).

Comment: Okay. The only assumption you need is that $f$ is strictly decreasing. In this case $f(\mathbb{R})$ is an *open* interval (bounded or unbounded), and $f$ is an orientation reversing homeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}$ to $f(\mathbb{R})$.